# alert javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function testing(){
    var search1 = document.forms['tfnewsearch']['search1'].value;
    if(search1 == null || search1 == "")
    {   
        alert("Error! Please type in something");
        isValid = false;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<form name= id="tfnewsearch" method="post" action="" onsubmit ="return testing();">
               <p><input type="text" class="tftextinput" id="search1" size="21" maxlength="120"/>
               <input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton"/></p>
</form>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

so what im trying to do here, is to show an alert pop if user doesnt type anything which is equivalent to null value but i dont understand why it doesnt show the popup. i think theres not error with my function,

Comment: Your html is invalid: 'form name= id="tfnewsearch"'

Comment: Your `name` tag was left open, making it invalid

Comment: And your form is outside the body.

Comment: OMG i cant believe i missed that. thanks guys sorry for my carelessness. i really thought my function was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gYg7r/

Here is how:

JS:

```
function testing(){
    var search1 = document.getElementById('search1').value; 

    if(search1 == undefined || search1 == ""){   
        alert("Error! Please type in something");
        isValid = false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="searchForm" id="tfnewsearch" method="post" action="http://google.com" onsubmit ="testing();">
    <p><input type="text" class="tftextinput" id="search1" size="21" maxlength="120"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton"/></p>
</form>
```